# Kibana doesn't show any results in "Discover" tab

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I setup elasticsearch and Kibana for indexing our application (error) logs. The issue is that Kibana doesn't display any data in the "Discover" tab.

**Current situation**

- Elasticsearch is up and running, responds to API
- executing a query directly on Elasticsearch like `http://elasticserver.com:9200/applogs/_search?q=*` returns lots of results (see below on how a single found record looks like)
- Kibana is up and running, even finds the `applogs` index exposed by Elasticsearch
- Kibana also shows the correct properties and data type of the `applogs` documents
- "Discover" tab doesn't show any results...even when setting the time period to a couple of years...

**Any ideas??**

Here's **how Kibana sees the `applogs` index**:

[image]

Elastic search query result object looks like this:

```
{
_index: "applogs",
_type: "1",
_id: "AUxv8uxX6xaLDVAP5Zud",
_score: 1,
_source: {
   appUid: "esb.Idman_v4.getPerson",
   level: "trace",
   message: "WS stopwatch is at 111ms.",
   detail: "",
   url: "",
   user: "bla bla bla",
   additionalInfo: "some more info",
   timestamp: "2015-03-31T15:08:49"
 }
},
```

..and **what I see in the discover tab**:

[image]

Comment: did you add timestamp while adding the index to kibana?

Comment: @Ngeunpo Could you detail what you mean exactly?

Comment: @Ngeunpo btw...the entries now flow in...didn't change anything..but still i'm missing a couple of hours the 1st day when I launched elasticsearch and started logging..hmm..

Comment: may be you should toggle with timeframe  from top right corner :)

Comment: @Ngeunpo Did that, if you take a look at the screenshot, it's set to "last 60 days", so that cannot be the issue.

Comment: @Juri I'm having exact same issue but I'm not able to get it working.  I have time search for year to date... still nothing.   Can you recall anything you might have done to get this working?  I've restarted kibana

Comment: @lazieburd Unfortunately not. Just keep it running for a while and see whether results start to pop up in kibana. Otherwise I'd check your  input pipes, like where you post data into kibana (i.e. through logstash) and make sure that works as expected

Comment: I have seen that also. Then after some time data appeared without any interventions. Today it disappeared again. Did you find root cause and solution how to fix/debug it?

Comment: If you did like me, you might **not have any timestamp data** in you data. Try to **uncheck** the `Index contains time-based events` when you are creating the index pattern.

Answer (score 160):

For people who have a problem *like* this:

Change time frame in top right corner.

By default it shows data *only for last 15 min*.

Comment: Well...if you take a look at my screenshot, that wasn't the case at all. I visualize the last 60 days. Anyway, the issue seems to be solved. The bad part is I don't have any clue why it didn't work initially. Will delete this question though, as it does not provide any solution

Comment: Also: Make sure to create and select the correct index you want to look at. Create it in the settings tab and select it on the left side on the discovery tab.

Comment: That's actually pretty hard to spot, nice answer.

Comment: yeah had the same problem so had to change it to this year and it started showing all

Comment: I have same problem and with more than 20k requests per minute, So the timeframe is not the root cause. I have also tried refresh the index pattern in settings as is advised below. Also didn't help. Last option could be to recreate the pattern, but then i will lose data generated by calculated fields i suppose.

Answer (score 30):

I wanted to put this as a comment but unfortunately, I am not able to given my deficient repo to do so. So as @Ngeunpo suggested, this is how you add a time field to an index while creating it:[image]. If you did not do that while creating your index, I suggest you delete that index and recreate it. The index name **logstash-*** in the gif is analogous to your index **applogs**. In this case, field **@timestamp** is added as the time field. Let me know if this works.

EDIT: Image courtesy: This [wonderful ELK setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-4-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 10):

Kibana does not understand the *timestamp* field, if it's format is incorrect.*Timestamp*, which you selected by clicking on **Time-field name** when Configure an index pattern, need to be :

```
"timestamp":"2015-08-05 07:40:20.123"
```

then you should update your index mapping like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/applogs/1/_mapping' -d'
{
  "1": {
    "timestamp": {
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
      "store": true
    }
  }
}'
```

See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158351/recognising-timestamps-in-kibana-and-elasticsearch)

**UPDATE**

If you are using ES 2.X, you can set the `"format"` to `"epoch_millis"` like this:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/applogs/1/_mapping' -d'
{
  "1": {
    "timestamp": {
      "type": "date",
      "format": "epoch_millis",
      "store": true,
      "doc_values": true
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: sample image for ELK creating index or pattern]

Try this: unclick "Index contains time-based events" checkbox
and then provide your index name then check "Discover" whether it contains data or not

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and this worked for me:

1. Delete the index from the Settings tab.
2. restart Kibana
3. then re-add in Settings

The issues with Time-Series I'm sure can also be an issue, but if no fields actually show up in the Discover tab, then you might have same issue as original reporter and what I had.

Comment: No need to restart kibana, just delete and re-add index

Answer (score 3):

I had probably the same issue - I see data in the dashboard but 0 results in discover. Going to Managerment > Index Pattern > Refresh filed list button (a button with refresh icon only) solved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and @tAn-'s comment helped me to resolve it. Changing date field to @timestamp did the trick. Thanx!

The next step should be to find out that was wrong with *my* custom date field.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but now its working fine.
The problem was with the @timestamp. Actually I have uploaded the file to `elasticsearch` using `logstash` thus it automatically generate a @timestamp field. `Kibana` compare time range with this @timestamp,that is, when the actual event occurred.Even if I deselect  "Index contains time-based events" option in add new index pattern page, `kibana` will automatically consider the @timestamp field.So toggle with timeframe on `kibana` based on the @timestamp field worked for me.
You can also check by adding index pattern with out a time stamp and deselect "Index contains time-based events" option.See what happens ..now there wont be any time frame select option in `kibana` discover page and you will most probably get the result in discover page.
These are all my observations, not sure, this solution fits your case ..you may try..
I am using ES 1.5x, logstash 1.5.1 and kibana 4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same error. *Mostly this happens because of time format*. Basically, make sure you have valid time frame for your data (top-right filter). Anyway,in my case, I used epoch time format for timestamp but it didn't work. So I changed to **epoch_millisec** instead and it worked like a charm.

In sum, make sure that Kibana can understand your date time format. It is required **epoch_millisec** by default not just epoch.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, everything was working previously and then I couldn't see the latest data starting February 1st (actually, I could if I looked back a month). It turns out that the mapping format for my custom timefield was incorrect. My mapping format was `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`. The problem was that `DD` is interpreted as day of the year and I wanted day of the month which is `dd`. Changing the mapping and reindexing fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I set time from server log.
and the time was different with UTC(the log's time was future comparing to UTC time)
so, when I search logs with filter of days/months/years ago. there was no log because it was future time.
so, when I use Today filter. or with future time.
It showed the logs.
after, changing the time zone. it's fixed

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Im having the same issue. What did you change the timezone to ?

Comment: Actually, My issue was similar. From your hint i could dig deeper into the issue. Looks like the Time i had posted ( local time) was considered as UTC. And hence time time adjusted in kibana was somewhere in the future ( almost like double conversion). Changing my code for timestamp, while posting to elastic, from LocalDateTime.now()  to LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")) seems to have done the trick. I had not realised till now that elastic was showing me the wrong time and it was not kibana's fault ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, So, as shown in one of the solutions above, I went to settings and deleted the previous index and made a new with @timestamp.

But that didnt solve the issue. So, I looked into the issue and saw, after a deployment, there was nothing coming into Kibana.

So, I went into the server, and saw that the indexes were corrupted. SO I just stopped the logstash and elasticsearch on the instance/server and restarted the service. 
And Voila , It successfully restarted the service and kibana was back.

**WHY DID IT HAPPEN ?**

Someone might have stopped the server abruptly which caused indexes to get corrupted.